# MySQL Select only some rows in pivot table and all rows in table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table `articles` with an `id` and a `name`, a table `company` with an `id` and a `name` and a pivot table (`article_company`) with an `id`, `article_id`, `company_id`, and a `price`.

I want to associate an article with a company so I need a request with all product and if they're associate to this company.

I tried this query:

`SELECT
  article_id,
  name,
  price AS price,
  1     AS associated
FROM articles
  JOIN article_company ON articles.id = article_company.article_id
WHERE company_id = 26
UNION
SELECT
  id   AS article_id,
  name,
  NULL AS price,
  0    AS associated
FROM articles
GROUP BY article_id`

but unfortunately I have both articles from articles table and company_article.

If it is not really clear, I want to have all articles rows but if an article is in company_article I want the row from that table.

**EDIT** : data tables :
- articles :

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Aez          |
|  2 | aze          |
|  3 | za           |
|  4 | azee         |
|  5 | article test |
|  6 | test 2       |
|  7 | Test 3       |
+----+--------------+
```

-company_article :

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| article_id | company_id | price |
+------------+------------+-------+
|          5 |         26 | 54.00 |
|          3 |         26 |  8.90 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

What I have and rows I want :

```
+------------+--------------+-------+------------+
| article_id | name         | price | associated |
+------------+--------------+-------+------------+
|          5 | article test | 54.00 |          1 | <
|          3 | za           |  8.90 |          1 | <
|          1 | Aez          |  NULL |          0 | <
|          2 | aze          |  NULL |          0 | <
|          3 | za           |  NULL |          0 | 
|          4 | azee         |  NULL |          0 | <
|          5 | article test |  NULL |          0 |  
|          6 | test 2       |  NULL |          0 | <
|          7 | Test 3       |  NULL |          0 | <
+------------+--------------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Table structures, sample data, expected outcomes

Comment: Just added tables articles and article_company and the rows of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I find myself this is the request I made :

```
SELECT article_id as id, name, price
  res.associated as associated, created_at
  FROM (
    SELECT
      article_id, name, price
      1 AS associated, created_at
    FROM articles
    JOIN article_company ON articles.id = article_company.article_id
    WHERE company_id = $id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      id AS article_id, name, null as price
      0 AS associated, created_at
    FROM articles) AS res
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY associated DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM articles a LEFT OUTER JOIN company_article ca ON a.id = 
ca.article_id;
```

This is the explanation for left outer join:
http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html